# How can I determine what libraries are dynamically loaded?

Tags: c++, windows, gdb

My program gives this error under gdb: `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.` I've put a breakpoint at `main`, `__main`, `__getmainargs`, `_imp____getmainargs`, and `mainCRTStartup` but none of them get hit before the error is thrown. I did a little googling and found that the error comes from a failed `LoadLibrary` call (which obviously, I didnt call).

So my question is how do I determine what library it is trying to load?

Comment: If you attempt to start the program without the debugger, you should get an exception that tells you the exact library you're missing.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore nope, bash even says that the exit code was 0 (although it verifiably wasnt run).

Comment: You're running on windows, right? Can't you just double-click the exe? :D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore haha, yea that pops the exception. thanks. if u add it as an answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the `exe` and an exception should be triggered, which shows the missing library.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)
This is a pretty fantastic tool that I use a lot in debugging loaded libraries.

Comment: I was going to say that.. "body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 28" is what stopped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try running your program under [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It should be able to tell you whats loaded, even if the program won't start.